# What is $\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{x-2}$?

Tags: limits

I tried multiplying by the conjugate which gave:

$$\frac{x-2}{(x-2)\sqrt{x+2}+2x-4}$$

But i'm still gettting $\frac{0}{0}$. According to my textbook the answer should be $\frac{1}{4}$, but how do I get there?

Comment: Have you tried L'hopital's rule?  It gives 1/4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

Multiply by the conjugate of $\sqrt{x+2}-2$ which is $\sqrt{x+2}+2$, was a good call; you just  made an error in your multiplication by the conjugate.

After multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{x +2} + 2$ we get $$\frac{x-2}{(x-2)(\sqrt{x+2}+2)}$$

Cancel the factor $(x-2)$ which appears in the numerator and in the denominator, $$\frac{\cancel{x-2}}{(\cancel{x-2})(\sqrt{x+2}+2)}$$to get $$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac 1{\sqrt{x+2}+2}\; = \;\frac 14$$

Comment: Alas. more targeted downvoting... we know who you are, both the mods and me!

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{x-2}&= \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{(\sqrt{x+2}-2)(\sqrt{x+2}+2)} \\
&=\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}+2}\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Note that the limit is by definition the derivative of

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}\implies f'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{x+2}}$$

thus

$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{x-2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2+2}}=\frac14$$

Answer (score 4):

For fun:

$\dfrac{\sqrt{x+2} -2}{(\sqrt{x+2})^2-4}=$

$\dfrac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{(\sqrt{x+2}-2)(\sqrt{x+2}+2)}=$

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}+2}.$

The limit $x \rightarrow 2$ is?

Comment: Nice idea Peter!

Comment: Thanks Gimusi.How do they say even a  blind chicken finds a kernel of corn now and then.:))))

Comment: But you are not blind and neither chicken! :)

Comment: Ok, half blind,sometimes  I read half the problem ,and sometimes I solve half the problem:)))

Comment: Then half blind I'm too!!!

Comment: Most welcome to the club:)

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=2+h$ and let $h \rightarrow 0$ hence
$$
\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}{h}=\frac{2\sqrt{1+\frac{h}{4}}-2}{h}=\frac{2\left(1+\frac{h}{8}-1+o\left(h\right)\right)}{h} \underset{h \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{4}
$$
Hence

> $$
> \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{x-2} \underset{x \rightarrow 2}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{4}]
> $$

Answer (score 3):

Hint
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{x-2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+2}+2}{\sqrt{x+2}+2}= \frac{\sqrt{x+2}^2-2^2}{(x-2)\sqrt{x+2}+2}$$
$$ \frac{x-2}{(x-2)\sqrt{x+2}+2}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}+2}$$

Answer (score 3):

It's the rate of variation at $x=2$ of the function $\sqrt{x+2}$,  hence its limit is the derivative:
$$(\sqrt{x+2})'_{x=2}=\frac1{2\sqrt{x+2}}\biggr|_{x=2} = \frac14.$$